# Is there an old pure p2p Skype version one could install and use it with others that have the same version?

Tags: linux, skype

*I'm aware this might not be the best place to ask this question, so I'm open to  redirect this to a more appropriate stackexchange site, feel free to suggest any.*

**Question:** The original Skype was - to my knowledge - based on a pure peer-2-peer protocol. Nowadays it is (more) centralized. Since I dislike the new versions more and more: Is there an old version that would still work on a modern linux distribution if you'd install it? It would suffice if it would work only with people who have the same version. Or was there always some central components that would make this impossible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This does not appear possible using Skype. See https://support.skype.com/en/faq/FA12381/what-does-it-mean-that-skype-is-moving-from-peer-to-peer-to-the-cloud:

> **Q: Why are peer-to-peer users no longer able to sign in to Skype?**
>
> **A:** We want to create the best possible app experience for our Skype users
>   which means we must make some changes along the way. These decisions
>   are hard to make but will enable us to focus our efforts on
>   transitioning Skype from a peer-to-peer video and chat app to a
>   modern, mobile friendly cloud architecture.  Skype on the cloud means
>   you can access all of your chats and shared images on any device with
>   the same Skype account and consume less battery power.

You can try using [Tox](https://tox.chat/) instead.

---

**EDIT:** I could not find any specific details on how the old P2P Skype architecture worked, or about the supernodes it used. So I decided to try it out.

First I tried installing Skype 2.1 for Linux from the Wayback Machine's archive of Skype.com, from 2010, [link here.](https://web.archive.org/web/20100509074852/http://www.skype.com:80/intl/en-us/get-skype/on-your-computer/linux) This was before the Microsoft acquisition. However I could not get it to install, either I missed something or archive.org's mirror of the file is corrupted. So I downloaded it instead from [uptodown](https://skype.en.uptodown.com/ubuntu/download/4167).

It installed without a hitch on Ubuntu 12.1. I ran [tcptrack](http://www.ubuntugeek.com/tcptrack-monitor-tcp-connections-on-the-network.html) and tried creating a new Skype account. Skype attempted to do so for about 3-4 minutes, and during that time it tried contacting a huge number of IP addresses, some of which you can see here. Throughout the account creation attempt the list kept jumping around, as it attempted to contact as many servers as it could:
[image]

After a few minutes, it reported that sign up failed:
[image]

I also tried signing in to my existing Skype account, with the same results.

I ran a few of these IPs through [iplocation.net](https://www.iplocation.net/). Some point to ISPs like TWC and Comcast. Others show more detailed organization names: Northern Illinois University, GoDaddy, CariNet, SoftLayer Technologies Inc.

So there you have it. To me this looks very much like a collection of companies that were hosting Skype supernodes. Now that they are offline, you can no longer sign in and use Skype.

Comment: The OP is asking if using the pre-Microsoft version is still possible, between people that stuck to it. Because what MS did was mostly transitioning a perfectly good P2P app into a barely working corporate-controlled thing.

Comment: @xenoid Don't all the old versions still sign in to a central server? It sounds like they've cut off access at that chokepoint

Comment: @Xen2050 If you can confirm this, then you have the real answer to the question.

Comment: @xenoid as Xen2050 says, even the old versions of Skype were "centralized" p2p. They made use of supernodes hosted by Microsoft to route the calls. And as written in the [Skype.com](https://support.skype.com/en/faq/FA12381/what-does-it-mean-that-skype-is-moving-from-peer-to-peer-to-the-cloud) link I quoted, "...peer-to-peer users no longer able to sign in to Skype". If you can't sign in, you can't make calls.

Comment: @wysiwyg Skype didn't always belong to MS. If the supernodes really were always there even before MS and are necessary for login and always were, then that's the answer. Is there any reference for older versions that indicates this? I'll wait a bit longer in case you or anyone can dig up something about the old versions, before I'd mark this as the accepted answer - as it correctly describes the current official status, but it's a bit unclear about older versions. (If there were versions old enough to circumvent their login-mechanism, they wouldn't write that in their FAQ^^).

Comment: @wysiwyg Also thanks for the Tox recommendation, I'll check it out.

Comment: @Darkwing Yes I haven't found anything yet that details exactly how pre-MS Skype worked, whether supernodes were used or not. However you got me curious, so I dug up the [Skype.com Wayback Machine archive page from 2010](https://web.archive.org/web/20100509074852/http://www.skype.com:80/intl/en-us/get-skype/on-your-computer/linux) (pre MS acquisition). Currently booting up a Linux VM, will let you know what happens.

Comment: @Darkwing I attempted to install and sign in to an old Skype version with no success. See edit to my answer.

Comment: @wysiwyg too bad. Thanks for the research though! So... what we need to do is take over one of those IP addresses, reverse engineer the super-node protocol and then we're good to go...^^ Okay, I guess I just need to look for something else...